# PHP : merge multiples arrays with common keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have 5 differents arrays in my script :

```
$array1 = array(

array( "id"=>"1", "title"=>"Batman" ),
array( "id"=>"2", "title"=>"Spiderman" ),
array( "id"=>"3", "title"=>"Titanic" ),
array( "id"=>"4", "title"=>"Dracula" ),

);

$array2 = array(

array( "id"=>"1", "releasedate"=>"1926" ),
array( "id"=>"2", "releasedate"=>"1956" ),
array( "id"=>"3", "releasedate"=>"2001" ),
array( "id"=>"4", "releasedate"=>"1982" ),

);
```

etc ...
As you see, info about movie number 1 is splitted on all the arrays (in fact -> 5 arrays). Then I would like to merge all my arrays to get something like this :

```
$array_FINAL = array(

array( "id"=>"1", "title"=>"Batman", "releasedate"=>"1926" ),
array( "id"=>"2", "title"=>"Spiderman", "releasedate"=>"1956" ),
array( "id"=>"3", "title"=>"Titanic", "releasedate"=>"2001" ),
array( "id"=>"4", "title"=>"Dracula", "releasedate"=>"1982" ),

);
```

I tried array_merge, array_combine, no good results. I also checked other topics on stackoverflow but no one help me (i may miss the one i need!)

Any help ? :)

**EDIT :** Sorry, i did would give a little more details ... rows in the arrays could be in misc. order, then according to my code example : the movie "Batman" can be in 1st row in the first array, but in the 3rd row in the second array...

Comment: You can first index the arrays by id, and then iterate over them, combining arrays that have the same key.

Comment: In a simple way you can't do it.

Comment: If from a DB you could get this all in one query.

Comment: Sorry, i did would give a little more details ... rows in the array could be in misc. order, then according to my code example : the movie "Batman" can be in 1st row in the first array, but in the 3rd row in the second array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of both arrays is the same, you can simply use

```
$array_final = array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

However, if you want to merge them by the "id", you need to loop through them. A solution with the complexity O(m*n):

```
$array_final = array();
// loop through all movies in array1
foreach($array1 as $movie){
    foreach($array2 as $movie_release) {
        if ($movie['id'] == $movie_release['id']) {
            $movie['releasedate'] = $movie_release['releasedate'];
            break;
        }
    }
    $array_final[] = $movie;
}
```

And a little less complex O(m+n):

```
// create arrays with the ID as key
$titles = array_column($array1, 'title', 'id');
$releasedates = array_column($array2, 'releasedate', 'id');

$array_final = array();

foreach($titles as $id => $title) {
    $array_final[] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'title' => $title,
        'releasedate' => $releasedates[$id]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is:

```
$array1 = array(

array( "id"=>"1", "title"=>"Batman" ),
array( "id"=>"2", "title"=>"Spiderman" ),
array( "id"=>"3", "title"=>"Titanic" ),
array( "id"=>"4", "title"=>"Dracula" ),

);

$array2 = array(

array( "id"=>"1", "releasedate"=>"1926" ),
array( "id"=>"2", "releasedate"=>"1956" ),
array( "id"=>"3", "releasedate"=>"2001" ),
array( "id"=>"4", "releasedate"=>"1982" ),

);

// here we create pairs `id => releasedate`    
$new_array2 = [];
foreach ($array2 as $v) {
    $new_array2[$v['id']] = $v['releasedate'];
}

foreach ($array1 as &$value) {
    // here we try to find key `$value['id']` in `$new_array2`
    // and get it's value
    if (isset($new_array2[$value['id']])) {
        $value['releasedate'] = $new_array2[$value['id']];
    }
}
```

If you're 100% sure that orders of `id`s are the **same** in **both** arrays you can just:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($array1 as &$value) {
    $value['releasedate'] = $array2[$i]['releasedate'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i did would give a little more details ... rows in the array could be in misc. order, then according to my code example : the movie "Batman" can be in 1st row in the first array, but in the 3rd row in the second array...

Answer (score 0):

See this code prototype (it is simple and don't need to explanations I believe):

```
$fArr = [];
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++ ) {
    $fArr[] = [
        'id' => $i,
        'title' => $array1[$i - 1]['title'],
        'releasedate' => $array2[$i - 1]['releasedate'],
    ];
}
```

[Sandbox code example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/39c1a52a90a04f99c275da3ccb447b80cf56eb74)

Comment: Sorry, i did would give a little more details ... rows in the array could be in misc. order, then according to my code example : the movie "Batman" can be in 1st row in the first array, but in the 3rd row in the second array...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your five arrays contain the id key, you can do this with a nested `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4, $array5) as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $result[$item['id']][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

The outer `foreach` iterates all the rows in all the arrays. The inner one loops over each column and assigns its value to the corresponding key in the result array.